# How to enable SCM polling on a pipeline in Jenkins DSL using casc

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have found multiple similar questions on here, but none that seem to answer my question.

I am running Jenkins casc and want to configure a pipeline to run every time there is a change to a github repository by polling that repository.

Via the web ui, I was able to create a job, specify the scm as 'https://github.com/my-user/test-jenkins', and set the schedule to poll the repo for changes every 2 minutes. This worked great, and runs the job every minute if there is an update.

However, I do not see any documentation on how to code this is casc so that this job will persist when I re-build the job-configurator.

What is the syntax to create this scm Poll job in jenkins?

Additionally, I would like to call a pipeline rather than a job. I imagine there is a way to call a pipeline from a job, however, I was wondering if it is possible to set up a pipeline directly to poll SCM.

I see I can specify the scm schedule in my pipeline's configuration, but cannot provide the git repo to monitor, so I am not sure how this would work.

Answer (score 1):

So this seems to work! Still not sure if it is possible to trigger a pipeline in this same manner

```
freeStyleJob('poll_scm_job') {
    scm {
        github('my-repo/test-jenkins', '*/main')
    }
    triggers {
        scm('H/2 * * * *')
    }
    steps {
        shell(readFileFromWorkspace('scripts/test/test.sh'))
    }
}
```

This specifies that my job will monitor the git repo provided in scm.

triggers{scm()} provides the interval at which to check if the current latest sha of the scm repo has updated since the last check.

In this case, every 2 minutes.